# How to avoid NPE when no values is specified for Spring JPA criteria

Tags: java, spring, jpa-criteria

I have a Spring JPA search criteria like below. Where area is an Integer.

```
cb.between(root.get(Property_.area), searchConstraint.getAreaMin(), searchConstraint.getAreaMax())
```

The question is, when the user does not specify an upper bound or lower bound in the search, the value is null and this results in NPE. One thing comes to my mind is to make an if check for null values and set the value to Integer.MAX_VAL if it is null as a work around.This way I can avoid NPE, but it is also going to create a lot of if else checks. So I want to know if there is a better way.

Comment: In my opinion you should never return null from such methods, but a default instead. So if it's a list then return `Collections.EMPTY_LIST`, if it's int then `0` or `Integer.MIN_VALUE` depending on context etc. Check out NullObject Pattern: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern. Maybe consider using `Optionals`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two cleaner solutions come to my mind:

- using Optionals e.g. `Optional.ofNullable(searchConstraint.getAreaMax()).orElse(Integer.MAX_VALUE)
- areaMin and areaMax should have sensible default values which are overwritten only if user provided some data ; the data itself should be validated

Comment: Thank you all for the valuable opinions. The last one Optional.ofNullable(searchConstraint.getAreaMax()).orElse(Integer.MAX_VALUE) works best for me. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

if getAreaMin and getAreaMax are NULL you can avoid/ignore to add this criteria .
if getAreaMin is NULL and getAreaMax is NOT NULL you can use le()  instead of between , and the same for getAreaMax with gt() method; 
'if' code is ok.

something like this :

```
 if(isNotNull(searchConstraint.getAreaMin()) && isNotNull(searchConstraint.getAreaMax())) {
         cb.between(root.get(Property_.area), searchConstraint.getAreaMin(), searchConstraint.getAreaMax())
 }else{
     if(isNotNull(searchConstraint.getAreaMin()){
          cb.gt(root.get(Property_.area), searchConstraint.getAreaMin());
     }else{
          cb.le(root.get(Property_.area), searchConstraint.getAreaMax());
     }
 }
```

Or you can create a util method like (but the prev variant is better dut to performance issue):

```
private Integer getValueOrDefault(Integer value , Integer defaultValue){
    return value==null ? defaultValue : value;
}
```

execute : 
cb.between(root.get(Property_.area), getValueOrDefault(searchConstraint.getAreaMin(), Integer.MIN_VALUE), getValueOrDefault(searchConstraint.getAreaMax(), Integer.MAX_VALUE))

Answer (score 1):

If both values can be null I'd suggest splitting the `between` query into two predicates and then combining them. This way you can also handle the case when **both**  of them are null:

```
List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
if (searchConstraint.getAreaMin() != null)
    predicates.add(cb.gt(root.get(Property_.area), searchConstraint.getAreaMin()))
if (searchConstraint.getAreaMax() != null)
    predicates.add(cb.lt(root.get(Property_.area), searchConstraint.getAreaMax()))
if (predicates.size() > 0)
    cb.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]))
```